# Improper permissions/image not found, relative paths

Tags: python, python-os

I am working on a project where I am turning my Python file into a .exe at the end, but every time I run it it gives me the following error:

`OSError: Failed to read "BIG FILE PATH"\img_folder\start.png because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format`

Here is my code:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
start = os.path.join(script_dir, "Agents", "start.png")
```

Folder setup goes like this:

MAIN_FOLDER > img_folder > start.png
> script.py

I don't think this matters much, but I get the error when I call a user-defined function and it tries to find the image.

I tried not using a relative path, but soon I realized that I would need to, since I'll turn it into a .exe.

Why does it not work?

Comment: You should present in a tree-like structure where the image is located relatively to the script. Maybe you must double *os.path.dirname*?

Answer (score -1):

If script_dir is the current path you can change it with:

```
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Comment: How is this different than *abspath* (especially if applied to *\_\_file\_\_*)?

Comment: Hey man i tried that but it just gave me the same error